# Are there any available resources to practice business and engineering cases?

Tags: interviewing, pre-screening

I am preparing for an technical interview where I will be asked a few brain teasers and I will be presented with business cases to analyze.

While I am looking up information about real cases the company has worked on so I can understand how they solved them, I would like to know:

**Are any resources available online about mock cases for people to practice on?**

Maybe a collection of questions that have been asked, or simplified real cases to take a look on.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search can reveal dozens of options, though a good number of them are behind pay-walls. Your best bet is to Google something along the lines of "{Language} practice questions" for examples of language specific things (you can replace {Language} with a concept like OOP or Algorithms and yield good results as well). One that I personally have enjoyed using is http://codingbat.com/java.

It is also worth looking into coding competition sites that are also a Google search away. They often have past examples for practice and provide regular, on-going, new problems to solve.